# Angled end cap on inline element

Tags: jquery, html, css

## Goal:

[image: angled edge sample]

A design calls for an angled edge on inline elements with variable text. It's long enough it might wrap lines, in which case the edge should be applied to the last line (as opposed to the whole block).

## My attempt:

### http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjLpG

[image: angled text with inspector]

1. add a span
2. on page load, use JS to get the height of the inline text
3. create a css trapezoid
4. use relative positioning to position

## Works, except:

1. It uses javascript
2. when the screen or text is resized, it tends to be off by one or two pixels. Safari and Chrome seem to differ in where they apply rounding, so I can't make it consistent.

Is there a better way I can accomplish this effect?

## Other failed ideas:

1. some other variation of fancy positioning?
2. anything + skewX (it's inline. no dice. all my usual nesting tricks are out the window.)

## Code:

```html
<mark>test text</mark><span class="edge">&nbsp;</span>
```

```css
mark {
    background: #f00;
    padding: 0.1em;
}
mark + span {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#f00 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-right-width:10px;
    border-bottom-width:0;
    border-left-width:0;
    position:relative;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('mark + span').each(function(i,span) {
        var $span = $(span);
        var $mark = $span.prev('mark');
        var markHeight = $span.innerHeight();
        var markPaddingTop = Number($mark.css('padding-top').replace(/px/,''));
        var markPaddingBottom = Number($mark.css('padding-bottom').replace(/px/,''));
        $span.css({
          top: markHeight + markPaddingTop,
          'border-top-width': markHeight + markPaddingTop + markPaddingBottom
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: remove &nbsp; or set font-size to zero which might not cause you the space there...

Comment: Yeah, That's probably the thing to do once positioned. I'm using the &nbsp; to size the span correctly, which is necessary so I can figure out what the heck height this inline text has. The innerHeight of the mark element isn't useful if it wraps lines.

Comment: Are you able to hard-code a line-height for the text, or is it variable?

Comment: Is that possible? I was under the impression that while line-height is used for spacing, the actual 'height of a line' (the part that gets colored in on a mark element, for example) is calculated from the font itself (so is not known until it's rendered).

Comment: @Ricky You're right.  What I'm asking is: are you able to determine ahead of time a line-height value that is big enough to contain the font?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfectly reasonable (hard-code if necessary!). I can't *quite* see how to make use of that short of going with Mr. Brunkhorst's solution below—which might be a reasonable compromise: just inline-block the whole thing!

Comment: @Ricky In that case, I had in mind exactly what Austin Brunkhorst just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is overkill for the desired effect. You can simplify everything by using absolute positioning and the `:after` pseudo class.

```
mark {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 0.1em;
    min-height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

mark:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

`50px` is a little arbitrary, so change all instances of that to whatever line height that you're interested in.

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rysIf)**

Comment: I agree that a pseudo element is probably a good approach, but your particular solution doesn't maintain the intention to keep the text inline (if you break the text to a new line, the new line background is as long as the first line).  You should make `mark` be `display: inline`.

Comment: Agreed, although I do like that it guarantees a definite integer height. I mean I couldn't even make the inline solution work with all the js I could come up with. Maybe pixels instead of ems would prevent some of the subpixel rounding variations.

Comment: @Ricky How important is it that `mark`'s content is inline? Line height calculation from what I gathered in testing is very browser specific and makes for a somewhat inconsistent solution across browsers. If it's very important, I'll update my solution with some JavaScript hackery.

Comment: Priorities: 1. something that renders without pixel errors. (This accomplishes that, and I really appreciate the help!) 2. protect my pride. 3. understand inline elements. So yeah, this'll work, although I'm left a little curious whether it's even possible to do consistently.

Comment: After some research, it seems as though pixel perfect `line-height` calculation for `inline` elements in JavaScript is something that is commonly hassled with.

Comment: Alright. Yeah, we're going with it. Part of the answer then, I think, is that it's just not a great idea to get tangled up in this stuff. Impact on the product = 0. (although a slight hit on my reputation with our designer when I have to go back to him and say, "Sorry, it's just too hard.") Thanks again!!!

Comment: Haha, sometimes the designers have to deal with it :)